# Why is polyester hydrophobic as well as insoluble in various organic solvents?

Tags: organic-chemistry, physical-chemistry

Polyester is known to be hydrophobic as shown by it's low moisture regain.

However, esters are at least somewhat hydrophilic and soluble in water. This decreases with the hydrocarbon chain length increase, but in the case of polyesters, this is accompained with a proportionate increase in the number of ester groups.

My attempts to explain this were as follows

1. The reason nonpolar molecules are not soluble in water is the H-bonded structure of water is disrupted - there's a loss in entropy; water molecules have to orient themselves in the form of a cage around the non polar regions.

In the case of a polymer chain of PET, the loss in entropy is greater than if we tried dissolving the individual monomer esters that constitute it in water. Therefore one is somewhat soluble, the other is not.

2. Since like dissolves like, and a polar aprotic solvent would not have the H-bonded structure of water that would be disrupted (and in fact since they are both polar aprotic, one would presumably become well incorporated into whatever bonding structure the other has), I would think a polar aprotic solvent would dissolve polyester.

Turns out that this isn't the case. In fact, "polyester fibres are generally resistant to organic solvents" (A. Bendak and El-Marfasi; [pdf link](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://jag.journalagent.com/ias/pdfs/IAS_4_4_275_284.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwiAir2T5d37AhWEeN4KHSPpAhcQFnoECAkQBg&usg=AOvVaw3sg51EkbnIfegmqv8ih5YN))

Perhaps, I thought, this might be because of the relatively crystalline structure of polyester that doesn't allow solvent molecules to penetrate it below its glass transition temperature.

However, polyester fibres are soluble in phenol and m-cresol. They [here](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Relative-solubilities-of-Polyesters-in-different-solvents-at-30-o-C_tbl2_286892808) also appear to be soluble in THF and DMF, but not the remaining organic solvents.

Why wouldn't the same issues that were occurring with water occur with these polar protic solvents (phenol and m-cresol), and why are polyesters soluble in THF&DMF but not other polar aprotic solvents.

Also, what is a good general framework to be thinking about the solubilities of substances in various solvents?

Comment: The solubility is one of the phenomena that are not entirely understood in chemistry. Why is silver perchlorate $\ce{AgClO4}$ soluble in toluene ? Why is silver nitrate soluble in water, ether and glycerin, but not in ethanol ? Look in the Handbook of Chemistry and Physics. You will find plenty of other surprising facts about solubility.

Comment: @Maurice Interesting. What is then the best way to think about solubilities? Do we just leave it to experiments & measurement?

Comment: You have written the usual tendencies about solubilities. But I am afraid the only sure method is experiment and measurement. Maybe some day in the future somebody would discover THE law. He will become the next Nobel Prize. Try ! Why not ? But you must know that you will not be the first scientist to have tried, and failed...

Comment: @Maurice Hmm. Alright.