# Change in chemical properties on polymerization

Tags: organic-chemistry, physical-chemistry

What I want to know is how should I expect polyesters, polyamides or other polymers derived from a monomer containing a certain functional group to behave and react chemically vs the monomer, as well as the effect of their structure in their fibre form on their chemical behaviour. Differences in reaction kinetics, and general trends in chemical behaviour to expect and be aware of. I.e In what ways would they be similar and differ chemically from the properties of the monomer from which they were derived

Comment: Following the logic of the 2nd paragraph, solubility of n-alkanes in non polar solvents should not depend on the chain length. But it does.

Comment: @Poutnik In the case of esters and an increasing hydrocarbon chain, it would make sense right, since the nonpolar component is increasing. But in the case of polyesters there is a proportionate increase in the ester groups

Comment: In my understanding, acidic hydrolysis is much slower than alkaline one. Kinetics on solid surface is supposed to be much slower that for liquid boundary or homogenic mixture, considering geometry, accessibility and intermolecular bonds.

Comment: Imagine a wooden log with equidistantly spaced children. Each child would randomly  try and stop trying to lift the log. Now keep prolonging the log with adding more children. Will be the probability of successful lifting the log independent on its length?

Comment: @Poutnik Ah okay. That makes sense. So esters would be in a liquid form & somewhat solubilised and so the reaction would be faster than the reaction on the solid surface of PET fibres. However, sometimes esters do clump together to form tiny solids (for example oligomers of esters, such as cyclic trimers). How would you expect the reaction to go in this case?

Comment: @Poutnik In the sense that the surface area and volume of these tiny particles would be very small compared to PET fibres. So would the reaction be slow like on the surface of PET fibres, or faster like if they were in liquid form

Comment: There is another factor. The parts and functional groups of the polymer molecule are held in their place quite well. It may affect even the thermodynamics, favouring the ester more.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141057/discussion-between-poutnik-and-xasthor).

Comment: That's pretty much repost of https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/169694/why-is-polyester-hydrophobic-as-well-as-insoluble-in-various-organic-solvents without analysis of the topic, but with another question added.

Comment: @Mithoron No it's not. Even if one of the examples is the same, the point in this question is I want to know how should I expect polyesters (or other polymerised forms of functional groups, like polyamides) to behave and react chemically in general compared to the monomers they were derived from.